# How to import js file as part of the angular library

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to use the user created js file from assets folder to do an import in component file as below

```
import * as Editor from '../../assets/ckedit/ckeditor';
```

But i receive error as

```
[error] Error: Could not resolve '../../assets/ckedit/ckeditor' from dist\test\esm2015\lib\template-setup\template-editor\template-editor.component.js
```

Angular version is 8 and typescript v3.5.3

Ckeditor folder consists of .js files for import

Comment: could you provide ckeditor content? also what is the extension of a file?

Comment: It’s a folder contains bunch of .js files

Comment: I suspect that the Angular CLI does not know about the `.js` files yet. This is why the `.js` files are not part of the build output and they can not be found when the applications runs. Did you add the `.js` files to the `angular.json` to `architect`->`build`->`scripts[]` array?

Comment: it would be better to import this library from node_modules instead of /assets folder. in this case there would be no problem with trying to integrate a library into the build process

Comment: @Andrei: If you want to integrate `.js` files from the `node_modules` they also have to be listed in `angular.json`. It does not make any difference, from which folder we want to include them.

Comment: no, it is not. you can use any library from node_modules, because webpack resolves this problem. You don't need to list all of your libs in angular.json

Comment: @Andrei: Can you show an example of this? There are several tutorials out there, that describe the opposite of your statement. For example:
https://medium.com/@clintpitzak/how-to-use-external-javascript-libraries-in-angular-8-247baacbdccf
Angular CLI adds the `<script>` tag with values that are configured in `angular.json` to the generated `index.html` in `dist`. Without adding them to `angular.json` they won't be automatically added to the build output.

Comment: i mean, if it is not a library, it will be included into a bundle by the webpack. just as `@angular/core` `@angular/material` or any other lib

Comment: `@angular/core` / `@angular/material` and other libraries like that are published in Angular Package format. They are supported by the Angular CLI by default., so it is true for them, that they are automatically included in the build. But if the installed npm package is a pure `JavaScript` library (not in Angular package format), then they won't be part of the bundle automatically. And the question is about a pure `JavaScript` library. So their `.js` files need to be added to `angular.json`.