# How to import custom built ckeditor 5 files inside an angular library

Tags: angular, ckeditor5

I am writing a angular library 'core-lib', which has a module 'rich-text' and it has a component 'rich-text-editor'.
This rich-text-editor component implements ControlValueAccessor and is a wrapper to custom built (after cloning) ckeditor 5.
I have the required files copied to assets folder inside the module

```
import * as ClassicEditor from '../../assets/js/ckeditor5/build/ckeditor';

@Component({
  selector: 'rich-text-editor',
  templateUrl: './rich-text-editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./rich-text-editor.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: RichTextEditorComponent,
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class RichTextEditorComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

  public Editor = ClassicEditor;
  :
  :
  :
}
```

When I build the library, I get this error:

*× Generating FESM2020*

*ERROR: Could not resolve "../../assets/js/ckeditor5/build/ckeditor" from "dist/core-lib/esm2020/rich-text/components/rich-text-editor/rich-text-editor.component.mjs"*

Any suggestion to resolve this will be helpful.

NOTE: This issue is similar to [How to import js file as part of the angular library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65605547/how-to-import-js-file-as-part-of-the-angular-library)

package.json contains:

```
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-adapter-ckfinder": "^40.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^7.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-autoformat": "^40.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles": "^40.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-block-quote": "^40.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ckbox": "^40.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ckfinder": "^40.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-cloud-services": "^40.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-easy-image": "^40.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic": "^40.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials": "^40.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-heading": "^40.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image": "^40.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-indent": "^40.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-link": "^40.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-list": "^40.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-media-embed": "^40.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph": "^40.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paste-from-office": "^40.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table": "^40.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-typing": "^40.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui": "^40.0.0"
```

And index.htmk:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>SearchApp</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body class="mat-typography">
  <ma-app-root></ma-app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please add your `package.json` and `index.html` file ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title is simply the meaningless repetition of the tags. The title should be clear and descriptive enough that its content is clear to a future site user who is skimming a list of search results.