# How to use ckeditor 5 packages inside an angular library

Tags: angular, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am writing an angular library **core-lib**, which I am using in my angular application **entity-app** (and some other apps)

This angular library (core-lib) has a module **rich-text** and it has a component **rich-text-editor**.
I want to use custom built (from https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/) ckeditor 5 in this.

Currently, I have the ckeditor 5 as a separate project (**rich-text-lib**) and do the following:

```
yarn install
npm run-script build
npm link
```

AND use it by linking
In 'core-lib':

```
npm link @prabhu/rich-text-lib
```

and in 'rich-text-editor':

```
import Editor from '@prabhu/rich-text-lib';
```

Also, in the angular project (entity-app) that use core-lib, I link it:

```
npm link @prabhu/rich-text-lib
```

If I try to build required ckeditor (with extra plugins say Font) directly inside core-lib, I cannot use it in 'entity-app' as I get error. Something like: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/14705

I cannot use webpack inside my angular app as it may result in breaking of Angular CLI.

**Is it possible to have this custom ckeditor 5 inside a angular library without using webpack?**

***Please note:***

- I am using @ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular.
- If I try to use the built ckeditor 5 artifacts (got from npm run-script build), I get issues mentioned in:
  [How to import custom built ckeditor 5 files inside an angular library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77436918/how-to-import-custom-built-ckeditor-5-files-inside-an-angular-library).
- Also, I should be able to write my own plugins to extend ckeditor feature